# How to test or enforce strings are valid nested properties on a TypeScript object?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I have a few arrays of nested property keys used to specify the order that properties of an object are displayed in different scenarios, like so:

```
interface PurchaseDetails {
  purchase: {
    date: string;
    details: string;
  },
  returned: string;
}
```

```
fieldOrder1: string[] = [
  "purchase.date",
  "returned",
  "purchase.details",
]
```

I want to at least unit test that the keys specified in these sort of arrays are valid to the type. Is that possible without creating a fully specified fake object manually? Can I unit test for TypeScript validity?

Alternatively, is there any way to type the `fieldOrder1` array to somehow only allow nested keys?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wO8kpN) meet your needs?  If not, please [edit] the question to demonstrate failing use cases or elaborate on what's missing.  Otherwise I can write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz I've just tried it out and it does seem to work, but in my actual situation it does trip up on other arrays (of field orders common between multiple scenarios) being spread into `fieldOrder1`. I guess I could mark it as answer but it kind of looks gnarly enough I probably would hesitate to use it in practice 

Comment: If you can provide a [mre] that demonstrates a use case that isn’t met, I might be able to amend the solution. As for gnarliness of the type manipulation, that’s just TypeScript for you.  Anyway let me know.

Comment: Actually, I think I've figured out some other confusing quirk I can't really explain here of our practical implementation that causes that to trip, but misleadingly looks like it's the spreads fault. I guess I could accept it as is as an answer.